# Is there any tools like "Blend" in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, blending, blend-modes

I have created a shape with "Blend" option in Illustrator (below)[image].Now I am trying hard to replicate that in Inkscape. Is there any way/option to do that in Inkscape? I have searched a lot with "Blend tool in Inkscape", but what I have found did not help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent in Inkscape is an extension called Interpolate. From the main menu it's located at *Extensions > Generate from Path > Interpolate*.

You need to have two paths selected to use it. Shapes such as circles, polygons, or rectangles need to be converted to paths first, using *Path > Object to Path*

Example:

[image]

**Edit:** Please note however: I can think of better ways to make such shapes without using the Interpolate extension.  A simple shape filled with a gradient would have a much smaller file size when saved as an SVG.